# Bash - mix/merge/combine two different arrays with same length

Tags: bash, array, bash-array

I have two different arrays with the same length:

```
s=(c d e f g a b c)
f=(1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5)
```

how can I *mix/merge/combine* this two arrays, so I would get this output:

```
c1 d2 e3 f1 g2 a3 b4 c5
```

Comment: If `zsh` is an option, you could use `${s:^f}` to zip the arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like: building a counter from 0 to arraylength - 1, then combining these elements from the arrays. Free-hand:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
...

len=${#s[@]}
for (( idx = 0; idx < len; idx++ ));
do
  echo "${s[idx]}${f[idx]}"
done
```

Comment: adding: `tr '\n' ' '` or using `printf "%s " "${s[idx]}${f[idx]}"` for getting it all in a row ;-) **THX!**